# why does my shouldOverrideLoading method never get called?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to show a toast on `shouldOverrideLoading`, however, it never gets called. My code is huge so I stripped it down into a way smaller code but I still can't find the mistake I am making. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private EditText urlEditText;
private ProgressBar progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);// Enable Cookies
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);// Enable Java Script
    webView.setWebViewClient(new ViewClient());

    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);// Enable Flash

    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {// ************************************
        // ON PAGE LOAD AND FINISHED
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(// hide_keyboard
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(urlEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        // **//
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Pull down to refresh",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            view.loadUrl("about:blank");
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setMax(100);
    // Use Done/search button in keyboard as go button
    urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    urlEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            CustomSearch();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}

public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}

class ViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "page started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public void CustomSearch() {
    // go button for searching worldwide
    urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
    String url = urlEditText.getText().toString();
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

}
```

Comment: After you set the `WebViewClient` to an instance of your `ViewClient`, you call `setWebViewClient()` a second time with an anonymous `WebViewClient` instance that replaces your `ViewClient`.

Comment: sorry mikey, i'm confused

Comment: You're calling `setWebViewClient()` twice. The second time "cancels" the first call, since there can be only one `WebViewClient`, so the `WebViewClient` you end up using doesn't have the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method. Get it?

Comment: it worked, but `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't get fired when changes in page occur via javascript, it only works when a new url is loaded :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new ViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);// Enable Flash
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    // ...
}
```

First, you pass a `ViewClient` instance to `setWebViewClient()`, and then, without ever using it, you overwrite it with a simple `WebViewClient` instance, that does not have your overriden `shouldOverrideLoading` method.